# Typo3 and own script in FlexForms

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

Is it possible to use my own PHP in flexform?
I need to read data from a txt file that I upload in the same FlexForm.
I guess I need to reload the flexform after uploading, but how do I read the context of the txt file and list it in the Flexform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user` type of field as described in [TCA](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html) docs.

Unfortunately I haven't any sample now, but there should be not problem to implement what you need. Tip: good IDE with some debugger will be your friend :)

Comment: Thank you. I was also looking for hooks. Maybe that could solve it too?

Comment: if you want/need to interact with these uploaded data `user` field most probably will be better, as you can use PHP and also JavaScript to handle some events during record editing. Hooks are mainly dedicated to perform some actions _after_ record saving attempt.

Comment: Hmm, haven't found anything usefull yet. Not even useful documentation. But maybe I am looking the wrong place.

Comment: Hm... I linked it already in the answer ... http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html   you'll find there sample field with some color... so instead you can insert any other PHP/JS code

Comment: Okay, maybe I just didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I made it with itemsProcFunc

```
<itemsProcFunc>tx_getDataFromXlsxFile->addFields</itemsProcFunc>
```

And the a claas.getDataFromXlsxFile.php file